# Get text from input text field in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am working with WKWebView and loaded url in the same web-view which is having login page (email and password input text).

email input text field like this:

`<input class="input" type="email" placeholder="" data-automation-id="email" name="email" maxlength="256" value="">`

Can someone guide me that how to get the value this input text?

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('email').value", completionHandler: { (jsonRaw: Any?, error: Error?) in
            guard let jsonString = jsonRaw as? String else { return }
            print(js)
        })
```

Tried this but not working :(

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add `id` to the element, use `getElementsByClassName` instead which returns an array and pick the first element to read the value of the email field:

**Example**:

---

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value") {(result, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        
        print(String(describing: result))
    }
}
```

Sample HTML string used for testing:

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="" data-automation-id="email" name="email" maxlength="256" value="5556454">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any chance to get the value if user edit the input text in webview?

Comment: @Arun To do that you have to inject JS and `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Arun cool, conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler`  and implement its method to receive the input text

Answer (score 0):

The `input` tag doesn't have an `id` of `email` which is why the lookup by id is failing. Update the web page so the `input` tag has an `id` set to `email`.

```
<input id="email" class="input" type="email" placeholder="" data-automation-id="email" name="email" maxlength="256" value="">
```

With the `id="email"` added, the `document.getElementById('email').value` should find the `input` and give you the value.

Comment: Thanks but document.getElementByName('email') not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Why are you using `getElementByName`? You need `getElementById` after adding `id="email"` to the `input` tag. And make sure no other tag in the document has an `id` of `"email"`.

Comment: But at this time we cant change the webpage.Do you have any alternative suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid that's the only way that I know. But I'm far from an expert in JavaScript. You'll have to research to see if there is some other form of `document.getElementByXXX` that will let you get that specific `input` tag without an `id`. Seems unlikely but maybe it can be done.